# Omniauth Facebook Devise fails production Heroku but works in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

I developed this app on Nitrous.io (using a heroku postgresql DB).  Omniauth works correctly when tested on that platform.  When I try on production Heroku, I get a "The parameter app_id is required" error from facebook.

inside devise.rb

```
config.omniauth :facebook, ENV["FB_APP_ID"], ENV["FB_APP_SECRET"]
```

My facebook developer site url's and callbacks are up to date. ENV variables are by Figaro, and again, it works fine when run through Nitrous.io.

Comment: Just to be clear, when you say "ENV variables are by Figaro", you mean you set your Figaro keys up on Heroku? i.e., you did something like "heroku config:set FB_APP_ID="?

Comment: No I was unaware I had to set them on heroku.  Thanks man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro

Did you try the following???

> Heroku
>
> Heroku already makes setting application configuration easy:
>
> $ heroku config:set google_analytics_key=UA-35722661-5
>
> Using the figaro command, you can set values from your configuration file all at once:
>
> $ figaro heroku:set -e production
>
> For more information:
>
> $ figaro help heroku:set

Answer (score 0):

You can also add/delete config variables by going to heroku settings then click on the reveal config variables button.